# Move span to the left within element

Tags: html, css, epub

I have a specific case where I have to float a span from the right to the left of the headline. Problem is that it needs to be CSS2 since it's for an epub2-book.

With what I have so far (see bottom) it looks good when it's one line:

[image: example of working condition]

but with less space, ergo when it's two lines, it ends up looking like this:

[image: example of issue]

I guess it happens because the span is still actually at the end of the `<h1>`, so it moves to the bottom line. I tried this with and without `vertical-align: top;` or `top: 0;` but that didn't work.

```css
span {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<h1>text hahaha I am such a cool text!
  <span>|left Text|</span>
</h1>
```

Is there any way to move the part to the beginning of the element? Or make it kind of float to the top? (Yeah, I know there's no `float: top;`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the width of your text is known you can hack it using `position:absolute` and `text-indent`

```css
span {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  text-indent:0px;
}

h1 {
  position:relative;
  text-indent:140px;
}
```

```html
<h1>text hahaha I am such a cool text!
  <span>|left Text|</span>
</h1>
```

Comment: Thank you! I had to add a width to the span the size of the text-indent of the h1 but now it works. Even in the most desastrous epub viewer called Adobe digital editions ;)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to have the span or can you use [:before](https://www.w3.org/TR/WD-CSS2/selector.html#didx-pseudo-elements-3)

```css
h1:before {
  content: "|left Text| "
}
```

```html
<h1>text hahaha I am such a cool text!
</h1>
```

Comment: Well, it's a label that changes from headline to headline so putting it in the css is sadly no option. but thanks.